# changing the description of a Telegram Group with the telebot libary

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Is it possible to change the description of a Telegram Group with the telebot libary?
Or is there another possibility to let two Telegram bots communicate with each other?

I intendet to use the Group description to let the bots communicate with each other since they cant send Messages to other bots directly.

Comment: do you control both bots?

Answer (score 0):

you can set the chat description with:

```
setChatDescription(chat_id, description=None)
```

I haven't found any methods to read the chat description so this might not be useful for your case.

source: https://telepot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html?highlight=setChatDescription#telepot.Bot.setChatDescription

if you are in control of both bots you can make them communicate directly (eg: with sockets)